How do you modify a mesh using ProBuilder in Unity
I am new to ProBuilder (and Unity).  I have a mesh I would like to modify.  Imagine a 2D L-shaped mesh (like an L-shaped table top) that I would like to modify to be a simple rectangle.
I have tried removing vertices or removing edges, but that does not seem to be part of the tool set.
Am I supposed to select an edge and 'collapse' the mesh into the proper shape?
Any hints or help would be appreciated.

Probuilder does indeed have remove verticies and edges. However, tutorials are off topic for stackoverflow

Which command?  Let me know and I will delete the question.

Its a menu option not a command

Is there a reason a normal cube would not work?  If you need a "simple rectangle", you can scale a cube to be the correct shape.

@hijinxbassist I wanted to use an existing object to modify.

You can remove or reduce mesh points by using 'collapse points' on the vertex menu.
You need to activate the option of 'collapse to first point'.  Then, you select a vertex you want to keep (first) and then select other vertices and use the menu command.
There is no command to remove vertices or edges.  In a way that makes sense, because it would be unclear what the remaining edges would be connected to, or that the remaining vertices would be single points in space.  That said, it is still a bit clumsy.  There may be a better way to do it, but this works.
